# meaning of parenthesis in R programming under levels

Tags: r, levels

```
l1 = factor(sample(letters,size=10,replace=TRUE))
l2 = factor(sample(letters,size=10,replace=TRUE))
l12 = factor(c(levels(l1)[l1],levels(l2)[l2]))
```

Note: letters gives lower case alphabets.

In the above example, could you please explain me what is the meaning of (l1)[l1]
and (l2)[l2] in line 3.

My samples and results:

```
> l1
 [1] y h f r x q y p d o
Levels: d f h o p q r x y

> l2
 [1] n n v d s h k w y q
Levels: d h k n q s v w y


> l12
 [1] y h f r x q y p d o n n v d s h k w y q
Levels: d f h k n o p q r s v w x y
```

Answer (score 0):

When an open parenthesis `(` comes after a name, R will treat whatever comes *before* the parentheses as a function and pass whatever is *inside* the parentheses to that function as arguments.

I start with this because functions are evaluated with high priority, so *"What is the meaning of `(l1)[l1]`"* is the wrong question, `levels(l1)` happens first, then `[l1]` happens to the result of `levels(l1)`.

For example:

```
log(1:3)
```

Calls the function `log()` on the vector `1, 2, 3`.

```
log(c(1, 5, 7))
```

Calls the function `c()` on 1, 5, 7 to create the vector `1, 5, 7`, then calls the function `log()` on the vector `1, 5, 7`.

```
log(c(1, 5, 7))[2]
```

Calls the functions `c()` and then `log()` as described above, and then calls the function `[` on the result, extracting the 2nd element of the result of `log()`.

```
factor( c( levels(l1)[l1], levels(l2)[l2] ) ) # some spaces added for clarity
```

- Calls the function `levels()` on the `l1` object

  - subsets the result with `[`, based on the values in `l1`
- Calls the function `levels()` on the `l2` object

  - subsets the result with `[`, based on the values in `l2`
- Calls `c()` on the results mentioned above
- Calls `factor()` on the result of `c()`

---

What is `levels(l1)[l1]` doing? As far as I can tell, this is a confusing way to get the same result as `as.character(l1)`:

```
set.seed(47) # for reproducibility
l1 = factor(sample(letters, size = 10, replace = TRUE))
l2 = factor(sample(letters, size = 10, replace = TRUE))

l1
#  [1] z j t v o r k m o y
# Levels: j k m o r t v y z
levels(l1)
# [1] "j" "k" "m" "o" "r" "t" "v" "y" "z"
levels(l1)[l1]
# [1] "z" "j" "t" "v" "o" "r" "k" "m" "o" "y"
identical(as.character(l1), levels(l1)[l1])
# [1] TRUE
```

So, overall, I think the goal of `factor(c(levels(l1)[l1], levels(l2)[l2]))` is to concatenate the vectors `l1` and `l2`, with a factor as the result. I think a clearer way to do this is

```
factor(c(as.character(l1), as.character(l2)))
#  [1] z j t v o r k m o y d s e p n x k a b m
# Levels: a b d e j k m n o p r s t v x y z
```